# Why did Russia vote to renew the arms embargo and other sanctions on Yemen?

Tags: russian-federation, sanctions, iran, unsc, yemen

On both [Feb 28, 2022](https://press.un.org/en/2022/sc14810.doc.htm) and [Feb 16, 2023](https://apnews.com/article/iran-politics-united-nations-yemen-sanaa-5d330e59db69f004ed286bab65e82f13) Russia voted to renew the arms embargo and other sanctions on Yemen. Why would they do that when Iran is probably not too pleased, given that e.g. the US 5th fleet has a clear mandate under international law to [intercept](https://www.reuters.com/world/us-navy-intercepts-massive-shipment-explosive-material-gulf-oman-2022-11-15/) arms and explosive supplies for the Houthis?

Comment: What is "thus legally" here? Do you mean that if there are sanctions, intercepting sanctioned cargo is deemed legal, thus whoever has the capability would not break laws seizing such cargo?

Comment: @Vesper: yes, otherwise the US would be acting as a party to the conflict. Like this, they just enforce a UNSC decision. Being a party to the conflict would not necessarily be illegal, granted, but more [politically problematic](https://www.hrw.org/news/2015/04/06/q-conflict-yemen-and-international-law). I've reworded it a bit.

Comment: oil politics. Russia has many angles, not just arms deals but also oil prices to think about. they maintain good relations both with the saudis and iran. https://www.reuters.com/markets/commodities/russia-saudi-arabia-discuss-oil-market-prices-wednesday-novak-2023-10-11/https://www.reuters.com/markets/commodities/russia-saudi-arabia-discuss-oil-market-prices-wednesday-novak-2023-10-11/

Comment: @Angriffsreiher: yeah, it appears that Russia was even slightly favoring the Saudis until recently "In October 2021, Russia voted against a Dutch resolution in the UN Human Rights Council that proposed extending the mandate of the Group of Eminent Experts (GEE) human rights investigators in Yemen. This resolution had been heavily lobbied against by Saudi Arabia."

Comment: And even now "In early April 2023, the lead frigate of Russia's Northern fleet Admiral Gorshkov made headlines when docking at the Saudi port of Jeddah, after participating in naval drills in the Indian Ocean and Arabian sea, the first docking there of a Russian military vessel in almost a decade." So, I've kinda self-answered here, but if someone wants to put these in an actual answer.

Comment: @Fizz why not write a self answer? those thend to be good, because all the research effort put into them. i wrote a short one, but the subject is bigger than the word "oil"

Comment: It's a proxy guerilla war between two very close neighbors that uses small weapons through Oman, Eritrea, Sudan and Djibouti. Eritrea is 20 minutes away on a fast boat. Oman traders have lots of routes. Oman has 50% ibadi and shia muslims, both are persecuted minority sects. Sudan and Eritrea have vast coastlines just 1hour from the Yemen coast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is oil. Russia's also has interest to maintain good relations with the Saudis, which seems to be very beneficial to both sides, and this vote might be a nod towards them.

> Russia, Saudi Arabia discuss oil market, prices amid Israel-Hamas war ([Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/markets/commodities/russia-saudi-arabia-discuss-oil-market-prices-wednesday-novak-2023-10-11/))

and while the US intended normalization, that is, the agreement between Saudia and Israel seems very unrealistic now, the raising oil prices for Saudia might be a good compensation.

As for Russia's relations with Iran and their mutually beneficial arms deals, Russia's policy in Yemen didnt harm them the slightest. Indeed arms deals aimed for a vast increase in size since [2022](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1296249/russia-arms-exports-by-country/#:%7E:text=India%20was%20the%20leading%20destination,to%20China%20in%20that%20year.):

> In the emerging arrangement between Russia and Iran to supply each
> other with weapons, the former has received hundreds of Iranian drones
> to rain on Ukrainian cities and civilian infrastructure, while the
> latter looks set to get Russia’s advanced Su-35 fighter jet. On top of
> that, Moscow has reportedly funneled captured U.S. and other Western
> weaponry to Tehran. ([Foreign](https://foreignpolicy.com/2023/04/19/iran-russia-arms-weapons-defense-exports-ukraine-war-middle-east/) Policy, 2023 apr)

Russia's goal is to supply arms to as many countries in the region as possible, and the recent developments suggest that their future prospects are looking good in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the 'probably because the Saudis wanted that' [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia%E2%80%93Saudi_Arabia_relations#:%7E:text=In%20October%202021%2C%20Russia%20voted,lobbied%20against%20by%20Saudi%20Arabia.):

Russia supported the Saudis vs the West in some respects in that conflict, e.g.

> In October 2021, Russia voted against a Dutch resolution in the UN Human Rights Council that proposed extending the mandate of the Group of Eminent Experts (GEE) human rights investigators in Yemen. This resolution had been heavily lobbied against by Saudi Arabia.

True, Russia is not too enamored of the West preaching human rights (and investigating abuses thereof), so their vote in that regard probably had more than one motivation.

Also,

> In early April 2023, the lead frigate of Russia's Northern fleet Admiral Gorshkov made headlines when docking at the Saudi port of Jeddah, after participating in naval drills in the Indian Ocean and Arabian sea, the first docking there of a Russian military vessel in almost a decade.

So they seem to be seeking other rapprochements with the Saudis, as well.

Answer (score -1):

Russia adheres to a constructive peaceful policy as far as it possible. All according to the UN Law and **with supporting the sovereign and legal Yemen government**. i do not understand why Russia should to do something other?

Iran politic was not well thought out. It was reactive and aggressive. But i think these agreements make clear [that peace line was won in this region with the help of China](https://www.wsj.com/articles/saudi-arabia-iran-restore-relations-in-deal-brokered-by-china-406393a1?mod=article_inline), and [Russia too ofc](https://www.txtreport.com/news/2023-08-02-ambassador-of-yemen--russia-sent-shipments-of-grain-for-free--and-we-aspire-to-establish-a-shipping-line-between-us.By-KThwjn.html), because Russia have good relations with Iran, Yemen, Saudi Arabia and all others in Middle East region.

> "Saudi Arabia, Iran Restore Relations in Deal Brokered by China." WSJ

And the US got only lots of Iranian assault riffles and ammunition, that [they had seni as support(read destabilise) to Ukraine](https://www.centcom.mil/MEDIA/PRESS-RELEASES/Press-Release-View/Article/3547919/) in current conflict bypassing the international law.

as the saying goes:
*Quae sunt Caesaris Caesari et quae sunt Dei Deo*

And finally, assault riffles are definitely not the best weapon for defence but [ground-air missiles](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/us-drone-shot-down-near-yemen-officials-2023-11-08/). So Yemen got [something more technological](https://abcnews.go.com/International/us-reaper-drone-shot-yemen-official/story?id=104729976), then lost before.